# Using Powershell W/ Web Platform Installer API Only Fetches x86 Installers on 64 bit Machine

Tags: windows, powershell, iis, web-platform-installer

I'm trying to write a script to automate the installation of the Application Request Routing package on a x64 Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS 8 and Web Platform Installer 5. I've reproduced the code I'm using below:

```
Try {
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller") | Out-Null
$ProductManager = New-Object Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ProductManager
$ProductManager.Load()

$product = $ProductManager.Products | Where { $_.ProductId -eq "ARRv3_0" }


#Get an instance of InstallManager class to perform package install
$InstallManager = New-Object Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.InstallManager

$installer = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.Installer]'

$Language = $ProductManager.GetLanguage("en")

#Get dependencies
$deplist = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.Product]'
$deplist.add($product)
$deps = $product.getMissingDependencies($deplist)
foreach ($dep in $deps) { 

        Write-Host "$($dep.GetInstaller($Language))"

        $Installer.Add($dep.GetInstaller($Language))
        Write-Host "Dependency $($dep.Title) not found..."
}

$installer.Add($product.Installers[1])
$InstallManager.Load($installer)

#Download the installer package
$failureReason=$null
foreach ($installerContext in $InstallManager.InstallerContexts) {
    $InstallManager.DownloadInstallerFile($installerContext, [ref]$failureReason)

    Write-Host $($installerContext)
}

$InstallManager.StartSynchronousInstallation()

notepad $product.Installers[1].LogFiles

Write-Host "Opening logs at $($product.Installers[1].LogFiles)"
Write-Host "Installation finished"

}
Catch {
    Write-Error "FATAL ERROR! $($_)"
}

Finally {
Write-Host "Press any key to continue ..."
$x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
}
```

The ARRv3_0 has two dependencies, ExternalCache and UrlRewrite2.

However, when I try to pull the installers using:

```
$Language = $ProductManager.GetLanguage("en")
$installer.Add($dep.GetInstaller($Language))
```

(where $dep is the reference to the product) it only fetches the x86 version, which will not install on a 64 bit machine. I've looked through the ProductList Xml that contains a listing of the Web Platform Packages [here](https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/5.0/WebProductList.xml), and I've copied and pasted below the occurrence of an x64 variant of the UrlRewrite2 package, which exists.

```
<installer>
    <id>20</id>
    <languageId>en</languageId>
    <architectures>
        <x64/>
    </architectures>
    <eulaURL>
    ......
</installer>
```

Interestingly enough, there's an architecture parameter, but looking at the [Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.platforminstaller(v=vs.90).aspx) there doesn't seem to be a way to set/access it. Other than hardcoding, is there any possible way to tell the API to fetch the 64 bit versions instead?

I'm definitely running this in a 64 bit powershell on a 64 bit machine, but it seems incredibly counter intuitive that the api would fetch x86 installers. Is there some incredibly obvious (and poorly documented) setting that I'm missing?

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The Product class as the Installers property. Instead of getting the default installer, I get a specific installer (64bit) and add it to a generic list of installers that is passed as argument to the InstallManager. Here is the snippet.

```
$installers = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.Installer]'

foreach($i in $product.Installers)
{        
        if($i.InstallerFile.InstallerUrl.ToString().ToLower().EndsWith("_amd64.msi"))
        {            
            $i.InstallerFile
            $installers.Add($i)
            break
        }
}
```

Comment: Filtering the installer by amd64 works for the product installers, but the dependencies listed are only an x86 installations.  Its like the Dependency list is built on the first installer of the product (x86).  I tried the GetInstaller for the product/dependency thinking that might be system aware, but it was not either.  I would like to have this figure out the correct dependencies, rather than having to manually figure it out and include them as root products.